# Set auto tags selection value from get query string in textExt jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-textext

Normally, tags value of TextExt jquery plugin is selected tags value when we press entry key; However, when loaded page, I have one `$_GET['name']="jam"` so I would to set auto tags selection of this value. How to do that intextExt plugin?

I would like to attach simple script as follows:

```
$('#textarea')
        .textext({
            plugins : 'tags autocomplete'
        })
        .bind('getSuggestions', function(e, data)
        {
            var list = ['David','Nary','Jam'],
                textext = $(e.target).textext()[0],
                query = (data ? data.query : '') || '';

            $(this).trigger(
                'setSuggestions',
                { result : textext.itemManager().filter(list, query) });

});
```

How to select auto tags selection of `$_GET['name']`?

Answer (score 0):

As shown on the example on http://textextjs.com/manual/examples/tags-with-items.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#textarea').textext({
    plugins: 'tags',
    tagsItems: [ 'PHP', 'Closure', 'Java' ]
});
</script>
```

"tagsItems" is where you set your default values.